# Invoking web service with flume

Tags: flume

I want to call an web service with flume and load the data into HDFS. Is it possible? I am new to flume. Can you help me understand?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Flume's [HTTP Source](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#http-source) with the JSON Handler, and then call that as if it was a web service. Then use the HDFS Sink to write to HDFS.

Comment: Hi, I understand the HTTP Source allows us to invoke a REST API, but if we need to invoke a SOAP Web Service, is there a way to do that with the HTTP Source? or with another existing Flume Source?